# error 500 after connect chat bot to cosmos db

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

I have a problem after connect my azure chatbot to the azure cosmos db , i have tried to run on my online editor and visual studio locally , but its not work in both platform.

the error is  here :

```
System.TypeLoadException
Could not resolve type with token 01000060 (from typeref, class/assembly System.Diagnostics.Eventing.EventProviderTraceListener, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.
```

Code:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{

 var uri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentDbUrl"]);
    var key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentDbKey"];
    var store = new DocumentDbBotDataStore(uri, key);

    Conversation.UpdateContainer(
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.Register(c => store)
                        .Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore)
                        .AsSelf()
                        .SingleInstance();

                    builder.Register(c => new CachingBotDataStore(store, CachingBotDataStoreConsistencyPolicy.ETagBasedConsistency))
                        .As<IBotDataStore<BotData>>()
                        .AsSelf()
                        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

                });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the example here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/DocumentDb/Global.asax.cs  It is also registering the AzureModule.  Have you tried that?

```
Conversation.UpdateContainer(
    builder =>
    {
        builder.RegisterModule(new AzureModule(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));

        var store = new DocumentDbBotDataStore(docDbEmulatorUri, docDbEmulatorKey);

        builder.Register(c => store)
            .Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore)
            .AsSelf()
            .SingleInstance();

        // Register your Web API controllers.
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);

    });
```

Comment: Also, when you deploy from visual studio make sure to check the box "Remove additional files at destination"

Comment: i have connected my cosmos db successfully , but i have another question , every time i store my conversation data , it only store one conversation data in my cosmos db , how can i save all my conversation data in my cosmos db?

Comment: ConversationData is not the same thing as message history.  In order to save message history, you need an IActivityLogger implementation.  This doc explains how to log messages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-3.0